# How do i get into pose mode?

Tags: pose-mode

I've made sure the settings are right from a tutorial I watched, and had the armature selected but whenever I go to the body or anything else, I can't go into pose mode. I don't even see a pose mode. Pls help

Comment: This is normal. Pose mode only for armatures, you can't select anything else. What do you want to do with other objects in pose mode?

Answer (score 2):

The Pose Mode **Exists only for Armatures** (Bones). The body is a mesh and not an armature. So to enter the pose mode you will have to **select the Armature** and not the body. Once you select the armature simply go to the pose from the menu above.

Tip: Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  to Enter the pose mode directly. (This is only for armatures)